# how to combine xhtml form with php codes?

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

this might be little confusing but i need to combine xhtml form with php codes. so here how it began: i created a search box and user searches for a product by typing a keyword or title and then my search page searches for the data from mysql and display the information in a table format. now my webpage suppose to compare the product information if from the displayed table if the user tick specific two rows of the result table and submit that again then it will take them to another web page where those two ticked product's price would be compared. i don't know exactly how i would do that so your suggestion would help me out.

```
echo "<table border='1' bordercolor='#000066'>
```

```
        <th>Item</th><br />
        <th>image</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>brand</th>
        <th>store</th>
        <th>Tick</th>

        </tr>"; // setting up the table headings.

        while ($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
            {
               echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5FFFF'>";
           echo "<td>". $query_row['title']. "</td>";
           echo "<td><img HEIGHT='250' WIDTH='250' src=fetch.php?imageid=".$query_row['productid']."></td>";

           echo "<td>". $query_row['description']."</td>";
               echo "<td>"."£".$query_row['price']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>". $query_row['brand']."</td>";
           echo "<td><a href=".$query_row['store'].">Click here</a></td>";  
                       echo '<td>';
           ?>

    <form action="tick.php" method="post">  <br /> 

           <input type="checkbox" name="compare" value="<?php echo $query_row['productid']?>" />select to compare<br /> <?php echo '</td>';
            } 

        echo "</table>";     ?>

       <input  align="right"type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Click to comapre" />

        </form>
```

the following code for

tick.php

```
<?php
```

$compare = $_POST['compare'];

if(empty($compare )) 
  {

```
echo("You didn't select any products.");
```

} 
  else
  {
    $N = count($compare);

```
 echo("You selected $N product: ");
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
  echo($compare[$i] . " ");
}
```

}

?>

Comment: i tried displaying product information in a table format and added and extra column in the table which has checkbox to tick the particular row of the result table but its not working. i'll try n edit my code in the question.

Comment: The whole story you described simply implies what you want to achieve and that can be done with no xhtml at all. It doesn't say anything about where and why you need to deal with xhtml.

Comment: i don't really know how would i work without no xhtml.the above code in question shows how the result from searching for products will be displayed.

Comment: What exactly is not working, what problems / errors are you seeing?

Comment: so when i search for a product(by typing keyword or title) it displays table with 2,3 products. i want to tick particular two product from that table using checkbox (this is displayed in the last column of the resulting table) and when i submit the button "click to compare" i want it to show me how many checkbox have i ticked but it only show me 1 whenever i tick more than one checkbox. it's confusing righ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert checkbox input box into array of checkbox as below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="compare[]"
```

Comment: Thank you. i have got something that i was looking for. i really really appreciate your help. have really good day and thank you.

Comment: @kiranpatel always welcome brother...+1 for question too

Comment: lol i'm girl.i no i have unisex name so no worries. :)

Comment: @kiranpatel Ohh okay sorry i did not knew it..Sorry..